# BaseDao for LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dao

I use linq DBML file for data mapping in my project. I have a lot of entities there, Like Areas, Locations, Departments, etc.
I want something like Base Dao that implements base functions like GetById, Add new, Update record, etc.
Currently I have BaseDao:

```
public class BaseDao
{
    protected DataModelDataContext dc
    {
        get { return DataModelDataContext.instance; }
    }
}
```

And all Entity Dao classes inherit this, like this:

```
public class AreaDao : BaseDao
{
    public Area Get(int id)
    {
        return dc.Areas.FirstOrDefault(u => u.AreaId == id);
    }
}
```

All I want to do is to move this Get method to BaseDao, to not write it for each entity Dao and make logic to automatically determine which table is to use there. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at implementing the repository pattern, check out this tutorial:
[Repository Pattern * Unit of Work](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)